# Wordpress - Adding two Adsense accounts to corresponding authors

Tags: php, wordpress, adsense

I am running a blog using the Wordpress CMS. Currently there are two authors for it. One is mine itself, and the other is my friend. Both of us have an Adsense account. We are going to monetize our blog. But I am confused with Adsense. Because money from his articles should be given to him, and other for mine. How is this possible? Any idea?

Or is it possible to know, if I add my Adsense account in the entire blog. And can I know how much revenue is generated from his posts? So I can pay him.

Something like this, Author 1's articles have ads from his own Adsense account.. And Author 2's articles have ads from his own Adsense account.

This is my blog - [www.tekyfox.com](http://www.tekyfox.com/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [Author Advertising Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/author-advertising-plugin/) as it allows the creation of revenue sharing programs (Adsense is supported along with many other Advertising Networks).

You will have complete control over:

- The percentage of author adverts to admin adverts.
- The user level that an author has to be before they get to participate in the revenue sharing program.
- Whether to randomize author ads on the front page of the blog.

Comment: I can't understand its working. Do I have to put 2 Adsense accounts there? Or only one? My blog has two authors. What I want is know how much revenue generated by each user. Is that possible with it. Something like this, Author 1's articles have ads from his own Adsense account.. And Author 2's articles have ads from his own Adsense account.

Comment: Your authors can add their own Adsense accounts and then you (the admin) can choose the ratio in which your own Adsense account ads should appear as compared to the Adsense account ads of your authors (50:50 etc). You can get more info from this link: http://www.slideshare.net/richardfedes/author-advertising-plugin-manualfull-guide

Comment: in my case one author is admin itself, and another one is simply an author. What if I want my Adsense ads on my posts and his Adsense ads on his posts. So should I set it to 0:100. So only his ads will be displayed. But what about admins posts?

Comment: You can use your current default Adsense account for admin user profile. Your requirements exactly match the purpose of this plugin. Just try it out.